# How to get JavaScript within HTML to work?

Tags: javascript, html, function, switch-statement

I am new to javaScript, I am trying to get a function to run on button click which I have created inside an HTML file. I want the function to return the values to a the paragraph tag in the html file.

Now, this is the first time I am trying this, I don't know how to pass the parameters from the textbox into the function of the script, and print the value to the paragraph tag. Can someone show me how, please.

Thanks

```
<script>
var calculateTotalCosts = function(salary,numWorkers,city)
    {
        fixedCosts = 5000;
        variableCosts = salary*numWorkers;
        switch(city)
        {
            case "BEJ":
                rent = 25000;
                break;
            case "NYC":
                rent = 30000;
                break;
            default:
                rent = 10000;
                break;
        }
        return rent + variableCosts + fixedCosts;
    };
</script>
Salary: <input type="text" value="Costs" />
No. Workers: <input type="text" value="Num of Workers" />
City: <input type="text" value="City" /><br />
<button onclick="calculateTotalCosts()"type="button">Calculate</button>
<p id="displayCost"></p>
```

Comment: You need to select the input elements' values as part of the click callback. You should be setting events in JavaScript, instead of HTML, similar to how you'd keep CSS in .css files, rather than inline in HTML.

Comment: @zzzzBov hey, I understand. I would've done it in seperate file but this is for a blog and I am only given a HTML file.

Comment: @Downvoter - This is a *perfect* question.  user123 has demonstrated an understanding of both HTML and JavaScript and now wants to learn how to tie them together to do DOM manipulation.  A perfectly concise and readable snippet of code was provided.  The explanation is neither too long nor too short.  The "what have you tried" question has been answered.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get element values and calculate them in function and pass it into p html elemnet

```
 <script>

    function CalculateCosts() {
        var costsVal = document.getElementById("costs").value;
        var workersVal = document.getElementById("workers").value;
        var cityVal = document.getElementById("city").value;
        calculateTotalCosts(costsVal, workersVal, cityVal);
    }

    var calculateTotalCosts = function (costsVal, workersVal, cityVal) {

        var variableCosts = costsVal * workersVal;
        var rent;
        switch (cityVal) {
        case "BEJ":
            rent = 25000;
            break;
        case "NYC":
            rent = 30000;
            break;
        default:
            rent = 10000;
            break;
        }
        //return rent + variableCosts + fixedCosts;
        document.getElementById("displayCost").innerHTML = rent + variableCosts;
    };

</script>
Salary:
<input id="costs" type="text" placeholder="Costs" />
No. Workers:
<input id="workers" type="text" placeholder="Num of Workers" />
City:
<input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City" /><br />
<button onclick="CalculateCosts()" type="button">
    Calculate</button>
<p id="displayCost">
</p>
```

Comment: Or you can use jquery: $('#displayCost').html(rent + variableCosts);

Comment: This is awesome, it works :). Just one question, so there is no direct way of passing the parameters to the function? We have to do it this way?

Comment: I edited answer. So function will accept parameters outside. In this case you can write intermediate function to collect parameters and pass them into your original function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your inputs id's or know which input points to what. See below:

```
 <script>
  function calculateTotalCosts()
     {
        input_text = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        salary = input[0];
        numWorkers = input[1];
        city = input[2];

        fixedCosts = 5000;
        variableCosts = salary*numWorkers;
        intcity = 0;
        if (city == "BEJ") { intCity = 0;}
        if (city == "NYC") { intCIty = 1;}
        switch(intCity)
        {
            case 0:
               rent = 25000;
               break;
            case 1:
               rent = 30000;
               break;
            default:
               rent = 10000;
               break;
    }
    result = rent + variableCosts + fixedCosts;
    document.getElementById("displayCost").innerHtml = result;
}
</script>
```

or use ids for inputs and that way you will be sure which input you are selecting.